# incomplete visit - Have you gone to the store yet?

Tags: present-perfect

When studying about the present perfect tense, I learned we use "gone to" instead of "been to" if the visit is not complete.

But today I saw the sentence below in Grammar in Use intermediate.

> Have you gone to the store yet?

I do not understand how 'you' and 'gone' can be used together. Have 'you' returned from the store here?

Can you tell me what this sentence means?

Comment: Have you been to the store yet - would be more common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So imagine that you tell someone "I am going to the store, do you want anything?". Later, they see you still around and do need something, they might ask "have you gone to the store yet? I need some milk." So gone refers to the act of traveling to the store and back. The idea that gone to can only be used for an incomplete visit is not something I am familiar with.

Note that "did you go to the store yet" would be a more common way of saying the same thing.

Comment: The rule the OP was taught has some validity, but is overstated. "He's gone to Australia" strongly implies that he's still there, but "He's been to Australia" implies that he has come back.

Comment: Your last sentence is presumably true for American English, but not for British English, where "Have you been to the store yet" is far more common.

Comment: @ColinFine As a Canadian, I also find *have you gone* to be much more common.

Comment: @JasonBassford: perhaps I wasn't clear. I certainly don't find _have you gone_ to be a likely way of asking whether you've been to the store and come back. I was responding to pboss3010's preferred phrase _Did you go to the store yet_, and saying that to me that is wholly unidiomatic. I was contrasting with _Have you been_, not _have you gone_.

Comment: @ColinFine I was simply adding that in addition to *have you been* being more common to *did you go* in the UK, I also find *have you gone* to be more common than *did you go* in Canada. It seems that *did you* (if only from this discussion) is specifically US phrasing. Whereas UK and Canada use *have you*.